# Android - app does not create files on the device

Tags: android, file, android-studio

I have developed an app for android. However, when I download it to the phone, it does not create a usual "com.appname" folder. When I go to the directory on my phone, a toast pops up that says "currently unable to download.please try later". Has anyone encountered this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy S3, btw

Comment: if you want package name folder and private data of app you must have root access. so on root /data/data/packagename/...(private files)

Comment: Anil please do not use comments to add supporting info to your question.  Edit your question when you have more to explain so readers don't have to go searching through comments for all relevant info.

Comment: It is completely unclear in which directory you are looking for that folder. Edit your post!